# Translating PersistenceException to DataAccessException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to handle unique key constraint violations in a Spring + JPA + Hibernate environment.

I use `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` to translate a `PersistenceException` to a `DataAccessException`. When there's a unique key constraint violation, I'd expect a `DuplicateKeyException` or a `DataIntegrityViolationException` thrown, but all I get is a `JpaSystemException` that wraps a `PersistenceException`.

Isn't the whole point of using the `DataAccessException` hierarchy that it's fine-grained enough not to have to look up the vendor-specific error code?

How do I have Spring translate a `PersistenceException` to a more specific `DataAccessException` ?

EDIT: I noticed that this.jpaDialect in DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary() is null. Is there some setting I need to configure to set this.jpaDialect to HibernateJpaDialect?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with @Repository annotation over DAO class? If so, what exception is thrown when it is not used?

Comment: @Tomasz Yeah, Spring does translate PersistenceException's, but to a JpaSystemException which isn't specific enough. Without translation, a PersistenceException is thrown.

Comment: Can you try adding breakpoint in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect#translateExceptionIfPossible` method to see how Spring translates JDBC/JPA/Hibernate exceptions behind the hood? It would also be great to see how does your complete stack trace look like, especially which exceptions are wrapped.

Comment: @Tomasz Execution does not reach the breakpoint.

Comment: This is weird, I just tried it with JPA/Hibernate and this is the place where exceptions are being translated. Could you put the breakpoint earlier in `org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils#translateIfNecessary`. I suspect you don't have a proper JPA dialect set. Are you sure it is `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect`? When you reach `org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean#translateExceptionIfPossible` with debugger, this dialect should be used for translation, but apparently it is not.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're onto something. Control reaches DataAccessUtils#translateIfNecessary but this.jpaDialect is null. Is there some setting I need to configure to set this.jpaDialect to HibernateJpaDialect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you don't have `jpaDialect` set. For Hibernate it should look like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```