# Spring Framework + Eclipselink + Exception translation mechanism

Tags: spring, eclipselink

This question is similar to the one asked almost two years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225437/translating-persistenceexception-to-dataaccessexception-in-spring-with-eclipseli). I am looking for some information how to handle exceptions thrown from Eclipselink 2.5 when some common database problems arise. What I am getting is ugly `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException` which does not give me any information about what fails. Let's take as an example simple entity:

```
@Entity
class Insect(_name: String) {

  def this() = this(null)

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  var name: String = _name
}
```

and equally simple repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
class InsectDaoImpl extends InsectDao {
  @PersistenceContext
  var entityManager: EntityManager = _

  override def addInsect(insect: Insect) = entityManager.persist(insect)
}
```

Executing following code:

```
insectDao.addInsect(new Insect("hornet"))
insectDao.addInsect(new Insect("hornet"))
```

Gives me:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.INSECT(NAME)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO INSECT (NAME) VALUES (?) [23505-172]
Error Code: 23505
Call: INSERT INTO INSECT (NAME) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(pl.zientarski.model.Insect@1df202be)
```

Yack! The exception itself does not say anything constructive about the source of the problem. Internal exception is first of all database-specific, secondly only the exception message explains what's wrong. For comparison, the same setup with Hibernate gives this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.INSECT(NAME)"; SQL statement:
insert into Insect (name) values (?) [23505-172]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Exception type instantaneously gives hint about what is going on.

The way Eclipselink works is not a surprise when you look into the source code of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex)` First of all it is not even overridden to support Eclipselink specific exceptions, secondly the default implementation inherited from `DefaultJpaDialect` expects exceptions deriving from `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`.

I wanted to ask you what are your best practises for working around this problem. Or maybe I just can't see the solution that is right there. Please let me know your suggestions.

The tests are made with Eclipselink 2.5 and Spring 3.2.3

Thanks.